# Error when running node web app created on windows for my raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi

I created a web application on windows which uses different packages.When trying to run it on my raspberry pi OpenCV gives an error: Invalid ELF headers

```
media/pi/WMORRIS/ProjectWV1/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:47
    throw err
    ^

Error: /media/pi/WMORRIS/ProjectWV1/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs.node: invalid ELF header
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/pi/WMORRIS/ProjectWV1/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:40:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Any tips or guidance would be great as I am not very familiar with raspian

Comment: Did you include the node_modules from windows to your rpi?  If so, try not to include it and do npm install on the rpi.  As some modules may have native compile codes for specific architecture is my guess.

Comment: When I tried to do npm install without including the modules it gave errors as well @noobius

Comment: error when npm installing packages or error when running the application?